# Geth - running out of disk space

Tags: go-ethereum, archive-node, disk-space

We are running a Ethereum archive node whose datadir size is almost 13TB now and our disk has started running almost out of space.

So, we are looking for a way to distribute the geth datadir to multiple server (if possible). One way that we've read is to shift the `ancient` folder to some non-expensive storage. But in our case, `ancient` folder is just 349GB. So shifting the `ancient` dir to different location will not solve the problem.

Can anyone pls suggest the alternate solution to distribute the geth datadir to distributed server/storage or any better alternative to handle increasing size.

Comment: [You can also explore running Erigon node instead of geth](https://github.com/ledgerwatch/erigon).